# How to adjust bubble images to text size in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

As a swiftUI beginner, I encountered a layout problem.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                print("Button pressed")
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    Image("tips")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("hello world")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

I hope that the background bubble image will change as the text changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a different approach, using `background` on the `Text`
and `scaledToFill`, such as:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                print("Button pressed")
            } label: {
                Text("hello world")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .background {
                        Image("tips")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```